# Exception runtime error through while loop

Tags: java

I wrote this code to get common prefix

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strs = {"flower", "flow", "fly"};
        String prefix = strs[0];
        if (strs.length == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
        for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
            while (prefix != strs[i]) {
                prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(prefix);
    }
}
```

but i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 0
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4601)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2704)
    at leetcode.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

can anyone explain why this error happened ?

Comment: Best see for yourself what is happening by walking through your code with a debugger, inspecting the variables. But also note that this, `while (prefix != strs[i]) {` is a problem since you shouldn't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs at comparison of the two string values you have use `!=` operator which will check the references and always true and from the while loop it will reduce the string up to empty and then throw the exception when prefix length become zero. `prefix.length()-1 = -1`

Use `!prefix.equals(strs[i])` equals operator instead.
Also to avoid the while loop iterate until prefix become empty use length comparison between prefix and the string value too. `prefix.length() >= strs[i].length()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strs = {"flower", "flow", "fly"};
        String prefix = strs[0];
        if (strs.length == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
        for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
            while (!prefix.equals(strs[i]) && prefix.length() >= strs[i].length()) {
                prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(prefix);
    }
```

This gives the output as : fl for your inputs.